# Theorem 9.13 An introduction to mathematical analysis

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

[image]

Someone please explain me that "since $c_k$ is arbitary ,we can conclude that.."

I mean how we got $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \nu(A_k)\leq \nu(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way: $c_k < \nu(A_k)$ is arbitary.

I choose $c_k$ such that $\nu(A_k)=c_k + \epsilon$   $...(1)$,where $\epsilon >0$, $\epsilon \to 0$

It is shown in the proof,that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_k < \nu(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$

$\implies\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\nu(A_k)-\epsilon)<\nu(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$ $..from(1)$

$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\nu(A_k) < \nu(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\epsilon$

$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\nu(A_k) \leq \nu(\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_k)$ $(\because \epsilon \to 0,\implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\epsilon \to 0) $ Please reply,am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

You have to just take limit as $c_k$ increases to $\nu (A_k)$.

Comment: $\nu(E)=$sup{$\mu(E):\mu \in \mathscr{M}$} is given. My question is,can $\nu(E)$ be always element of the set?

Comment: Becoz if  my set {$\mu(E):\mu \in \mathscr{M} $}$=${$0.9,0.99,,0.999,..$},then the supremum 1 may not belong to the set.please reply

Comment: @mathstudent Supose $S$ is  set of real numbers and $x \leq M$ for all $x \in S$. Then $\sup (S) \leq M$. This does not require the sup to be an element of the set.

Comment: so we may not have $\nu(A_k)=\mu(A_k)$ for some $\mu \in \mathscr{M}$

Comment: $\nu (A_k)=\mu (A_k)$ may not hold and it is never used in this proof. @mathstudent

Comment: I have tried to answer my own question in the above post,will you please see and inform me whether I am correct or not...

Comment: @mathstudent Yes,your proof is correct.